# How do I add a keyboard shortcut for a new exporter in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode

I added an S5 exporter for org-mode files, but I can't seem to find any documentation about adding a new exporter to the `C-e` menu, nor does the Customize menu provide any information. How would I, say, add the shortcut `C-e 5` to the command `org-export-as-s5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs 24.3.1 org-mode defines this menu as a list hard-coded in the definition of ORG-EXPORT (see `C-h f org-export`; if you have the Emacs Lisp sources installed, this will include a link to the function definition, and you'll find the keystroke definitions laid out in the binding form of that function's opening LET. (In my Emacs, the binding of interest begins at line 1008.) This is somewhat unfortunate for your purposes, because it means that cleanly adding a new exporter will require redefining ORG-EXPORT, which is a fairly complex function. (This assumes you don't want to edit the library source, which I would not recommend doing.)

On the other hand, having just checked out a copy of the current Org-mode source in order to write and submit a patch making the export backend list customizable, it looks as though the maintainers have stolen a march on me with Org version 8.0, whose new export engine allows for user-defined backends such as yours. [It appears](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/org/org-version.el?h=emacs-24) that Emacs 24.4 will package Org 7.9.3f as part of its standard library; however, the Org version currently available through ELPA is 20131202, which certainly does include the change.

I'd therefore recommend installing the current version of Org via `(package-install 'org)`, and then familiarizing yourself with the new export engine and how it manages its backends; from there, you should be able easily enough to work out how to integrate your export backend with the existing scheme. (The documentation on how to do so seems a bit uncertain at this point, but you might start [with the overview](http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/ox-overview.html), which is a little thin but provides links to resources which should help a fair bit.)

Comment: whew, heavy, but good news. I'll have to hold off on upgrading org until I'm ready to learn, but I appreciate the heads-up.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander Glad to be of help. And, yeah -- I was figuring on a fairly reasonable amount of work to patch Org 7 for an extensible backend list, but it looks like Org 8 just guts that whole end of things and replaces it entirely -- it also discards a lot of the export formats which Org 7 supports, leaving various flavors of iCal, HTML, LaTeX, and plain text. That's maybe not so great, but on the up side, it should be easier to integrate your S5 exporter, I think, and porting the discarded formats' exporters probably wouldn't be that hard for someone who cared to do so.